# Google Analytics - Different users on same public computer have same User ID metric

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics

I have an app where we track user id's from session and pass to custom metric in Google Analytics.

What we're seeing is that if you log out, and log back in as a different user, both users will use the latest user id within google analytics.

Is it possible to "clear" this common link between each session so that each sign in starts it's own session in GA?

Here's the same thread topic on ga forum: https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/96259041?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `clientId` when you create the tracker. i.e.:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {
  'clientId': '<my custom clientid>'
});
```

You will have to find a way to get it new on next time and pass it to the snippet above (or via GTM). For example, you can write it in a cookie that is deleted when you close the browser, in this way for the entire duration of the navigation it will be maintained and the next time you open the browser you have another one created and you will use that, and so on.

Comment: This is an approximation, considering that you have the problem in question whether you have 2 identical users or 2 different users, you can consider a new navigation as a new session. Alternatively, provide more details on what actually happens to that PC.

Comment: This is the example:

User A logs onto the device, they fill out an intake. They log out. Then, User B logs onto the device, they do the same thing. Then, User C. Etc, etc. I'm passing a user_id from the system to this, but, our analytics are showing all of those as the "last user ID" in the chain.

Comment: Ok, by default, a _ga cookie expires after 2 years from the date it was last refreshed. Every time a new hit is sent to google analytics, the cookie is refreshed. So in your case you have to set your own cookie expiration time by using the cookieExpires field. The solution is delete _ga cookie when user leaves.

Comment: What's the best way to handle this in your opinion: 1) delete the cookie on "log out" (but then what happens if they just close the browser? or 2) delete the cookie on "new session" and then manually refresh? (which seems super hacky)

Comment: In any case there may be some inconsistency so I would say that it can be more or less valid at login.

Comment: I actually just went a different route and logged the user id to a hit scope and it works

Comment: Of course, but in this way for Google Analytics you will always be the same user (as well as cases of the same session), this was not your initial request.......

Comment: I know it wasn't my original request, but I had to move on and it wasn't working as intended.